# Why was my question closed as too localised?

Tags: discussion

I have a legitimate question on enterprise web-sites, and it was closed, with no close votes, and only one -1.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49368/does-a-web-site-has-to-be-slow-to-be-enterprise

Why?  Also, why is there no button to reopen?

Comment: This question could have been closed as off-topic, not constructive, and not a real question. I'm surprised you actually think it should be left open. Please read the [faq] and [about] pages to get a better understanding of how this site works.

Answer (score 4):

You wrote a tongue in cheek question and you are surprised that it got closed?

When you ask a question that isn't serious, you are doing a dis-service to everybody that takes the time to read it.

Comment: It's a legitimate and scientific question, with scientifically significant data points as input, and I desire an answer.  It's not a one-off occurrence when an enterprise web-site loads slow -- it's pretty much the norm amongst many enterprise web-sites, and I would like to know why and whether it's something that is important to have in order to be perceived as enterprise.  The pages in question aren't even dynamic per se, yet somehow it still takes seconds for them to be generated.

Answer (score 3):

Your question was closed for several reasons, mainly because in its current form it is unlikely to help anyone else visiting Pro Webmasters, also the question is a little non-constructive because the question covers a grey area. Pro Webmasters likes questions to be answered by Facts. Such questions as: `Enterprise web-sites get better ranking from Google and other search engines?` is impossible for our visitors to answer and will be pure speculation - because no one knows for sure if Google treats big sites differently on page speed ranking factors, this question could also engage into debate which is not allowed according to our FAQ.

To answer your question, no you should not add a 1sec delay to your site to mimic larger sites.. Google rewards for page speed as we know, but no one knows to what degree and if large sites are not factored in.

There are actually lot of page speed related questions that may be helpful to you:

- [Why is loading speed of a website important for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42967/why-is-loading-speed-of-a-website-important-for-seo)
- [What's an acceptable "Avg. Page Load Time"?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28220/whats-an-acceptable-avg-page-load-time)
- [How can I simulate a slow connection for page load?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/861/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-for-page-load)

Finnally you may want to relook how your testing your page speeds, ping is not an accurate measure of time it takes a page to load. You could have a server with a ping that has 1000ms response  but renders the page quicker than a 100ms site.

Comment: It is a fact that Pro Webmasters is visited by Google employees, some seem to be in their official capacity.  There's nothing that precludes them from answering this question, except that you've just closed it, and now they can't, even if they've wanted to.  Please reopen the question.

Comment: We have had Google employees answer Webmaster related issues, we have never had any Google employee answer any questions relating to their ranking algorithm (as far as I know), and I'm pretty sure will never will on such a question that openly admits that larger organizations get different treatment on their algorithms. Without engaging into any more debate than I have, I will forward your concerns regarding this question to the other moderators.

Answer (score 3):

The privilege to vote to [Reopen](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) a question is based on [Reputation](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), and is covered here in the FAQ's that John suggested reading:  [All Privileges](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/privileges)

I think the moderators clearly made the right decision:

Before it was closed, I reread the question several times and still had a hard time understanding its logic. I suggested some edits to at least clarify it, but they were rejected twice… Perhaps I missed something, but at least that should have brought it to your attention that there were problems with it and it needed revising (not to mention my comment relaying that too).

I also happened to read some of the other questions you previously asked and noticed that you hadn't accepted any answers, other than your own twice. And some of the comments also seemed a little less than appreciative for the effort people were making, for example: [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48138/yandex-metrica-can-i-redirect-from-favicon-ico-to-the-11-gif-counter).

I'm a little green here and still learning myself, but I think if you have the perspective that this is a community-based site and that your questions, answers, and comments should benefit others as well, then you'll likely find better responses to them.

That being said, I think you have quite a bit of knowledge and experience and hope you continue to contribute.

Comment: Dear @dan, FYI: user @bybe has repeatedly spammed my questions with extremely broad and general answers that had nothing to do with the questions; his question (which you've kindly referenced here above) of what my own answer was about clearly demonstrates that he didn't even bother reading the question, other than looking at the `favicon` and `404` keywords.

Comment: Well, I'm a believer in Karma, especially on the net. If someone puts something out there that others don't like, it will come back to them - just look at YouTube ;-) I think bybe genuinely tried to answer your questions, and provided resources too. I wouldn't take any of this personally, or lose track that it's a good resource for people who want to learn and share.

Comment: @cnst Incidentally, I also asked an apparently "questionable" question that didn't fair well with others (so just deleted it). I chose to just learn from it and move on - hope you do to.