# Who has downvoted my questions?

Tags: discussion, support

On Pro Webmasters, a number of my open questions and answers have been suspiciously downvoted (unfairly, in my opinion), whilst the answers by others to my own questions (to those same questions which are being downvoted) are being upvoted, also unfairly, IMHO.

[Yandex.Metrica: can I redirect from /favicon.ico to the 1×1 gif counter?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48138/yandex-metrica-can-i-redirect-from-favicon-ico-to-the-11-gif-counter/48272#48272)

To be more specific, answer by @bybe to my Yandex question above is completely generic and inapplicable, yet it has been upvoted, and my own answer, where I answer the question after implementing the idea and hypothesis of the question, has been downvoted at the same time.  This cannot have been done in good faith.

Also, another question has been downvoted today, with no explanation whatsoever:

[https and Google Search: how to run an https web-site to get Referer?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49399/https-and-google-search-how-to-run-an-https-web-site-to-get-referer)

Another one has been downvoted several weeks back, again, no explanation:

[How do I prevent duplicate indexing by Googlebot-Mobile?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44920/how-do-i-prevent-duplicate-indexing-by-googlebot-mobile)

Who does this, and why?

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that when a user down votes a question, they lose a reputation point as well.  Because of that, down votes are sparingly used.

Even as a moderator, I do not have access to records of who upvotes and downvotes.  I can only speak for myself.   I put a down vote on the answer you provided at [Yandex.Metrica: can I redirect from /favicon.ico to the 1×1 gif counter?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48138/yandex-metrica-can-i-redirect-from-favicon-ico-to-the-11-gif-counter/48272#48272) because it doesn't make sense to me.

Bybe comments, "what works?"

Instead of answering him, you ask if he read the question.

I think you mean that the possible solution that you posted into the question itself works, but I have two problems with that:

- It isn't clear what "it" is in your answer.  If you do indeed mean the possible solution you stated in the question, you should say so explicitly.
- Answers belong in the answers section, and questions belong in the question section.  It is poor format to mix the two.

For the record, I have also up voted some of your other questions and answers.

---

Every time somebody down votes they *should* comment as to why they do so. I apologize if the reasons are not always clear to you.   Many of the down votes you received are appropriate, but I urge down voters to explain their reasoning.

---

Your behavior on this site has not been exemplary. Here is a list of things you have said on this site that I would urge you to edit out.  These are abusive and unkind:

- did you not read the question?
- I'm not sure I even understand the rationale of your answer
- Am I an idiot
- @bybe has repeatedly spammed my questions with extremely broad and general answers that had nothing to do with the questions

You [already know that I think one of your questions was not asked in a serious enough manner to considered a good question](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1026/14543).

---

The feedback that you get from our site (from votes, comments, and through meta here) is designed to let you learn from your mistakes and to improve.  If you wish to continue to contribute to this site, I would like to see you:

- **Work on the formatting of your posts.** -- When you get answers that are not what you expect, it is often because your question is too dense.  Try to find shorter ways of saying what you are asking.  Use formatting tools like lists to put the meat of the question in a place that is easily scannable.
- **Become more patient.** -- We work with technical questions that often take time to understand.  It is not surprising that you get answers that show that somebody does not fully understand what you are asking, even when a question is asked well.  You will need to restate the question for them in those cases. Take those times as opportunities to look for ways to edit your question to make it clearer.
- **Stop using belligerent language.** -- I'm not happy with what you have said on this site in the examples that I stated above.  Find ways to point out misunderstandings or mistakes without questioning the intelligence of others or making them feel bad.

Comment: My yandex metrica question specifically has a code snippet, and the question is, effectively, asking if the snippet is going to work.  Sorry, there's just no way to express this in a more clear fashion.  If the person answering, or the voter, doesn't know what `307` is, then perhaps instead of answering the question they don't understand (or voting down the correct and actually applicable answer, and voting up the offtopic one), they should instead be asking their own questions about the stuff they don't understand; in fact, that's what usually happens on other SE web-sites.